# Get Image File Information using MediaInfo library in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, mediainfo

I have been trying for more than two days to get JPEG Image and MP4 Video File Information using `MediaInfo.DLL` in my Pascal Script.

But I keep getting error

> Runtime Error (at 6:366) - Access Violation at address 0042FD23. Read of address 8065241E.'

The error mostly points to (at 6:366).

I can't think what problem is causing this exception when trying to get Media Information using `MediaInfo.DLL.`

The code I added to my Script:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: Lamborghini_Aventador.jpg; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: MediaInfo.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
type
  PWideChar = WideString;
#endif

const
  StreamKind_Image = 5;
  InfoKind_Text = 1;

function MediaInfo_New: Cardinal;
  external 'MediaInfo_New@{tmp}\MediaInfo.dll stdcall delayload';
function MediaInfo_Open(Handle: Cardinal; File__: PWideChar): Boolean;
  external 'MediaInfo_Open@{tmp}\MediaInfo.dll stdcall delayload';
function MediaInfo_Get(Handle: Cardinal; StreamKind: Integer; StreamNumber: Integer; Parameter: PWideChar; KindOfInfo: Integer; KindOfSearch: Integer): PWideChar;
  external 'MediaInfo_Get@{tmp}\MediaInfo.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure RetrieveImageInformation;
var
  IHandle: Cardinal;
  Width: PWideChar;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Lamborghini_Aventador.jpg');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('MediaInfo.dll');
  IHandle := MediaInfo_New();
  MediaInfo_Open(IHandle, PWideChar(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Lamborghini_Aventador.jpg')));
  Width := MediaInfo_Get(IHandle, StreamKind_Image, 0, 'Width', InfoKind_Text, 0);
  Log('Width of the JPEG Image: ' + PWideChar(Width) + '.');
end;
```

The line which the exception is generating is:

```
Width := MediaInfo_Get(IHandle, StreamKind_Image, 0, 'Width', InfoKind_Text, 0);
```

I expected that the compiler output will be `Width of the JPEG Image: 1920.`

I use latest version of Unicode Inno Setup Compiler (5.5.9 - U)

Thanks in advance for your important help.

Comment: Where did you obtained those DLL Calls for `MediaInfo.DLL`? Are they obtained from the Delphi Example comes with it?

Comment: Yes @GTAVLover......... I think they're fine.......Your recommendation is also fine.......Just what I want is to get CMD Output via `LoadStringFromFile`.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`MediaInfo Command Line Interface`](https://mediaarea.net/download/binary/mediainfo/0.7.87/MediaInfo_CLI_0.7.87_Windows_i386.zip) with Inno Setup Ansi or Unicode Version.

Usage Example:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: MediaInfo.exe; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: Dontcopy

[code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
   ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
   ExtractTemporaryFile('MediaInfo.exe');
   ShellExec('Open', 'MediaInfo.exe', ExpandConstant('"YourFileName.mp4" --LogFile="YourFileName Prperties.log"'), ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
   if SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError) = SysErrorMessage(0) then
   Result := True;  
end;
```

Now, navigate to the Inno Setup Temporary Directory as Administrator using Run (Windows Key + R) Command and see your Media Information Log File exists there which contains the Information about the File you given in the Command.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can call a function that returns a pointer to a string (character buffer) from Inno Setup Pascal Script.

But you can hack it like this:

- Declare the function as if it returns `Cardinal`;
- Use some available function that takes a pointer and copies it to another pointer. Declare the source pointer as `Cardinal` and the target pointer as `string`. One such function is the [`StrCpyN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcpynw).

```pascal
function MediaInfo_Get(
  Handle: Cardinal; StreamKind: Integer; StreamNumber: Integer;
  Parameter: string; KindOfInfo: Integer; KindOfSearch: Integer): Cardinal;
  external 'MediaInfo_Get@{tmp}\MediaInfo.dll stdcall delayload';

function StrCpyN(S1: string; S2: Cardinal; Max: Cardinal): Cardinal;
  external 'StrCpyNW@shlwapi.dll stdcall';
```

```pascal
var
  P: Cardinal;
  S: string;
begin
  P := MediaInfo_Get(IHandle, StreamKind_Image, 0, 'Width', InfoKind_Text, InfoKind_Name);
  S := StringOfChar(' ', 1024);
  StrCpyN(S, P, Length(S) - 1);
  S := Trim(S);
  ...
end;
```

The code requires [Unicode Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) (the only version as of Inno Setpu 6).

Comment: It seems bit hard, how can I declare `StrCpyN` ?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot the `StrCpyN` declaration. Added now.

Comment: This works well, but I can't sure will it work well in all Windows versions..... :-(

Comment: Why do you think this won't work on all versions of Windows?

Comment: Is `StrCpyN` exist in all Versions of ShlwAPI.DLL including W. XP and 98?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thx for giving this hacking method, but I don't see any performance difference between getting those info using MediaInfo Library and retrieving them (like -GTAVLover said), using Command Line and getting CMD Output via `LoadStringFromFile.` That's Why?

Comment: The `StrCpyN` is definitely available on Windows XP too. Not sure about 98. Do you even expect the Media Info to run on 98?

Comment: To me a hack is calling an external exe to retrieve media file information. Anyway, I was just answering your question (why the `MediaInfo_Get` is crashing). Chose the solution you like.

Comment: Yes....... Is the crashing of the function `MediaInfo_Get` caused the shown exception ?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I just asked..........It is good to hear `StrCpyN` exists in XP too.........Thank you for the given Important Information about `StrCpyN` Function.......... ;-)

Comment: No the exception is caused by Inno Setup Pascal Script not being able to handle the `PChar` returned by the function. Not by the function itself.

Comment: I finally like to know will this work on both Unicode and Ansi Inno Setup Compiler.

Comment: As is, the code works on Unicode version only. While the code can be made running on Ansi version, you should not use the Ansi version nowadays anymore.