# Get Handle to the Notepad and get Text in it as a Result in Pascal Script - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, notepad, pascalscript

I want to get the Text in the opened Notepad Window to use this text for my next functions.
If Notepad is open, (Visible or Hidden), I want to get its Handle using `FindWindow`and get the text displayed in its working area using `WM_GETTEXT`.

I need a proper function to do this.

I also read about [getting text from Another Window.](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=176341)

**UPDATE**

Now I obtained Handle like this:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  ResultCode, Notepad: Integer;
begin
   if CurPageID = wpReady then begin
       ShellExec('Open', 'Notepad.exe', '', '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
       Notepad := FindWindowByWindowName('Untitled - Notepad');
       if Notepad <> 0 then begin
         ShellExec('Open', 'TaskKill.exe', '/F /IM Notepad.exe', '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
         Log('Handle to the Notepad has been allocated. HWND is - ' + IntToStr(Notepad));
       end;
   end;
end;
```

And I need to get its text as String.

Please Guide.

Comment: How do you tell, which Notepad window is the right one?

Comment: I want to say like `MYTEXTFILENAME.txt - Notepad` according to the text file I am opening in Pascal Script.

Comment: Why do you even use Notepad? That's so unreliable! Why don't you load the file into `TMemo`?

Comment: no no I also had an encoding problem like this question shows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844156/inno-setup-pascal-script-loadstringfromfile-not-loading-strings-correctly That's why I loaded it inot Notepad. :-(

Comment: That's a hack, not a solution.

Comment: But. this is the only way..... :-(

Comment: But this function will be useful to anyone who wants to load texts from anothe windows in pascalscript.

Comment: No one really wants to load texts from another window! This is only ever used in hacks. Not in real solutions!

Comment: You didn't tell us what is the problem you are trying to workaround. Maybe you should ask a question about your actual problem, and not about your hack. This is typical [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: And this is also a hack.......But it works . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064058/get-image-file-information-using-mediainfo-library-in-inno-setup-pascal-script/39091095#39091095 :-(

Comment: This is the problem. I wanted to load text from another window in Inno Setup Pascal Script.

Comment: This is my actual problem!